# Why my PHP validation doesn't check for the existing email address in the database?

Tags: php, validation, email

I have a basic registration form with jaquery validation for all inputs and php validation to check for the existing email address. However, if I type the same email address and submit it several times, I don't get any validation messages and the email gets stored inside the database. I cannot understand why does it happen, I don't think I have any errors in my code.

Here is the PHP validation:

```
 public function register_post(){   
    $register = new Register();
    $register->loadFromPost();

    $valid_error = array();

    if($register->is_value_exist('email', $register->email)){
        $valid_error[] = 'email already taken';
    }

    $regexp = "/^[^0-9][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[@][A-z0-9_]+([.][A-z0-9_]+)*[.][A-z]{2,4}$/";

    if (!preg_match($regexp, $register->email)) {
        $valid_error[] = "not a valid email";
    } 

    $var_array = array($register->first_name, $register->last_name);
    $regexp = "/^[a-zA-Z]{2,16}+$/";
    foreach($var_array as $var){
        if (!preg_match($regexp, $var)) {
            $valid_error[] = "not a valid input value for first name or last name";
        }
    }
    if(count($valid_error) == 0)
    {
        $hash = Membership::hash($register->password);
        $register->password = $hash['password'];
        $register->hash = $hash['salt'];
    }
    $register->save();

    $redirect_url = SITE_URL . "home/index";
    redirect($redirect_url);
}
```

Comment: invalidate all assumptions, and remove that "when I submit" condition. Isolate this code for testing against the databse, so that you can call it as `trythisthing("lol@cats.com")` in a separate, dedicated script. Remove the part that tries to validate the address against the regexp and just put in emails that you know are valid. Then see what the db part does. Does it work fine? Great, the problem is in your RE validation (which you shouldn't roll yourself, it's super complex and you should just use a premade validator for them)

Comment: Badly broken regex, dont validate emails like that, e.g. limiting to a 4 character TLD is a bad idea

Comment: You didn't show us what `is_value_exist` does so only psychic powers can help here.

Comment: "I don't think I have any errors in my code." - that's a very bad attitude.

Answer (score 1):

Your save and redirect ALWAYS get called because they aren't in your IF condition.  Change to:

```
if(count($valid_error) == 0)
{
    $hash = Membership::hash($register->password);
    $register->password = $hash['password'];
    $register->hash = $hash['salt'];

    $register->save();
    $redirect_url = SITE_URL . "home/index";
    redirect($redirect_url);
}
```

These three lines should only get called when there are no validation errors.  You also need to create a way to send your valid_errors back to the user so that when they don't get redirected, they know why.

Since someone commented on it...as for regexs for e-mails, take a look here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html.  You aren't allowing a + or % or . -- etc.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this fully jquery like my code**

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
//validation 
     $("form[name='your form name']").validate({ 
            rules: {
                uname:{
                    required:true,
                    alphabetsnspace:true,
                    minlength: 3,
               },
                email:{
                    required:true,
                    email:true,
                },

                }, 
                psw: { 
                    required: true,
                       minlength: 5,
                       maxlength: 25,

                  }, 
                  rpsw: { 
                    equalTo: "#psw",
                     minlength: 5,
                     maxlength: 25,
               }
            },
            messages: {
                uname:{ 
                    required:"Please enter your user name",
                    minlength:"User name should be more then 3 characters",
                    alphabetsnspace:"Only alphabets and numbers are allowd",
                      },
                email:"Please enter a valid email address",

         },
//calling php 
            submitHandler: function(form) {
                $.ajax({
                    url :"register.php",
                    type:"post",
                    dataType : 'html',
                    data:$('#registerform').serialize(),
                    success: function(data) 
                    {
                     //any function
                     }
                   });
    });
    });
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to that code. Why do you think that it solves the problem?

Comment: r u want validation or what to email several inset stop?

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

try this for email several inset validation

```
if(isset($email))
{
 $checkdata=" SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' ";

 $query=mysqli_query($conn,$checkdata);

 if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
 {
  echo "email already taken";
  exit;
 }
 else
 {
//inset
}
```